# SQL Server Group a promotion by last 24 hours, last week and last month and sort by week descending

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm trying to look at how successful different promotions have been in the last 24 hours, week and month. To get the amount by promotion for the last 24 hours I've used this code but I don't understand how to get another two columns for the last week and the last month.  And then finally I want to order it by the amount in the last week descending. I want to be able to run this query at any point during the month. Please help me.

```
SELECT Promotion
     , Sum(Amount) AS Last_24
  FROM   dbo.CustomerPayment
 WHERE  Started >= DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()) 
 GROUP 
    BY Promotion
```

Comment: sample data, and desired output will make sure the output is what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single query :

```
SELECT Promotion
     , Sum(CASE WHEN Started >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Last_24
     , Sum(CASE WHEN Started >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Last_Week
     , Sum(Amount) AS Last_Month
  FROM   dbo.CustomerPayment
 WHERE  Started >= DATEADD(day, - 31, GETDATE()) 
 GROUP 
    BY Promotion
 ORDER BY Last_Week DESC
```

Note that this part :

```
WHERE  Started >= DATEADD(day, - 31, GETDATE())
```

as te be clarified following your own interpretation of "Last Month" concept.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation -- that is, move the conditions to the `select`:

```
SELECT Promotion,
       SUM(case when Started >= DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()) then Amount end) AS Last_1_day,
       SUM(case when Started >= DATEADD(day, - 7, GETDATE()) then Amount end) AS Last_7_day,
       . . . 
FROM  dbo.CustomerPayment
GROUP BY Promotion;
```

One possible issue, though.  `GETDATE()` -- despite its name -- returns a time component to the date.  I suspect that you might actually want to treat this as a *date*, not a *datetime*:

```
SELECT Promotion,
       SUM(case when Started >= DATEADD(day, - 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) then Amount end) AS Last_1_day,
       SUM(case when Started >= DATEADD(day, - 7, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) then Amount end) AS Last_7_day,
       . . . 
FROM  dbo.CustomerPayment
GROUP BY Promotion;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for month / week. Not 7 / 30 days.

If you wish those, just use variables to have that query readable.

```
declare @monthstart date,
        @weekstart date
;
select @monthstart=datefromparts(year(current_timestamp),month(current_timestamp),1)
select cast(DATEADD(d,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,current_timestamp),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as date) as Sunday,
    cast(DATEADD(d,2-case when DATEPART(WEEKDAY,current_timestamp)=1 then 8 else DATEPART(WEEKDAY,current_timestamp) end,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as date) as Monday
;
```